# How to uglify css in vue cli?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-cli

I create a vue application using the cli: `vue create vue-app`.

I create a scss file in `src/style.scss` and I import it using main.ts: `import './style.scss`.

```
.some {border:1px solid red;}
```

and in app.vue:

```
   <div class="some">...
```

How I do css uglify when I build the application in prod? before uglify: `.some { display:block; }` after uglify: `.x {display:block;}`.

I add `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin` to my `vue.config.js`.

after I compile I open the css file in dist folder, and the class name (`some`) is the same..

```
.....a[data-v-32fde4c9]{color:#42b983}.some{border:1px solid red}
```

vue.config.js:

```
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

     configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css\.scss$/g,
                cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
                cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                    preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
                },
                canPrint: true
            }),
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you already run `yarn run prod` or `npm run prod`? Usually the prod build already contains uglifying..

Comment: `npm run build` make a build for production.

Comment: Yes. A minified build for production. What else do you need?

Comment: I need uglify css.. not minified. read my question please :)

Comment: The real question here is why would you need uglifying in Vue when you have [`scoped` CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html) and [`module` CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html)? What's your final purpose? Because the purpose of uglifying is scoping, not CSS cosmetics, and Vue already provides that out of the box, using scope attributes.

Comment: The point I'm making here is you simply shouldn't use `class="red"` on the element if you don't want it in your markup. You can use scoped vue components at every single level and each of them will have their "ugly" attributes so that you don't use any "nice-name" classes, if that's what you want. The fact you can use human readable classes and rely on them in your app is an optional feature, not a bug. If you don't like them, simply develop your entire app without using a single class.